# How to use jquery: globalize - Date module in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, globalization

i am trying to use jquery:gloablize - Date module in meteor. I am creating a package for it:

```
Package.describe({
   summary: "Jquery Globalize package"
});

Npm.depends({
   globalize: "1.1.1"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('lib/globalize.js', ['client', 'server']);
  api.add_files('lib/globalize.cultures.js', ['client', 'server']);
  api.add_files('lib/number.js', ['server','client']);
});
```

But when loading the "number.js", meteor throws the following error:

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

What is the right way to load the files that are required to user the jquery:globalize - Date module

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the ? char after your filename.

```
'lib/number.js?'
```

Comment: Thanks elGusto. But it did not solve the problem. I had just edit the question as i had overlook the "?" when posting the question. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to just simply upgrade your meteor version to the beta of 1.3 using meteor update --release 1.3-beta.12, you would benefit from npm modules, no need to wrap them in meteor packages anymore. [link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.3/packages/modules/README.md)